# How do I add <p> tags using PHP code?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules

In PHP I would like add a field of type paragraph (`<p>`) to some content. Using site-building I have no problem but I can not find the way to do it correctly using PHP code.

Comment: Maybe be a little more descriptive or show some code you tried to make it work to get a specific answer.

Comment: Reworded title as a question, grammar in the body

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
  //Suposse that in $content it is the content html of the page
  $content .= "<p>Lorem ipsum</p>";
  echo $content; 
?>
```